# As a TA, how much information should I share with the professor about students?

Tags: teaching-assistant, privacy

This is my first semester being a TA. When students email me and include personal reasons (e.g. sick family member or mental health struggles) when they ask for things like extensions or to switch recitation slots, how much detail should I include when raising these issues to the professor teaching the class? I want to be careful about respecting their privacy, but also making sure that I'm not overstepping as a TA. I'm way overthinking this, but like I said, it's my first time TA-ing!

Comment: Some of the answers bring up legal considerations, and those vary by location.  It will help those trying to help you to specify where you are.

Comment: As a TA, do you have the authority to grant extensions, or to change recitation slots?

Comment: @BobBrown What legal considerations would be involved in sharing information between a TA and their instructor?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I don't know.  In the United States FERPA would be the governing Federal law, the law covers "education records,"and the test that would apply is whether there is "legitimate educational interest in the education records."  Conversations between student and TA almost certainly aren't "education records"and the professor clearly has a legitimate educational interest, so probably no FERPA.  No HIPPA because the TA is not a "covered entity."  Things might be very different in other countries. (Not a lawyer, not legal advice, etc.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since the professor is ultimately responsible for the class and for the student outcomes, there is very little that should not be shared. Many things need to be shared to protect student welfare, in fact, and you are probably not in a position to make decisions.

Something like mental health issues in particular, including feelings of suicide, need to be shared since you aren't a mental health professional and the professor has more experience (though isn't a professional either). The professor probably knows the appropriate response, such as referral to a counseling office.

Trivial things need not be shared, but anything that potentially affects student outcomes and might require interventions should be.

You can also ask the professor for general guidance on this. In fact, if you have group meetings it would be useful to do it there so that all the TAs get the same advice.

Comment: That makes sense! I hadn't even considered the possibility of requiring interventions. Thanks for your response, I'll definitely bring it up with the professor!

Comment: @Lyra-xy An important point is also: Giving the information to the professor does not make you a "snitch". You are part of the teaching body, and the student knows that, and they still volunteered the information to you. They don't expect that things they tell you won't be relayed to the professor.

Comment: Depending on where in the world you are, there are likely specific laws on the sharing of personal information, and in particular privacy of sensitive information. So asking professor/employer for guidance should be the first thing you do; indeed they should already have provided training on this subject.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that, in most US jurisdictions, TAs, professors, other instructors are mandatory reporters, meaning that if a student shares that they are suicidal, or have been the victim of a sexual assault, or are in a similar kind of situation, one might be legally *required* to report that to someone higher up (for a TA, telling the lead instructor is likely appropriate).

Answer (score 4):

When it is sent to your address you may not even be allowed to share it.
Here it is important to distinguish, if the student had the expectation to reach you as a person (possibly trusting you more than the professor) or the expectation to reach some lecture related address which may spread the e-mail to different people, rely it to a mailing list or post it into some internal chat system.

I think it is reasonable to assume that an e-mail sent to "firstname.lastname@" is meant not to be shared with other persons without asking, while one can assume that mails to an address that does not specify the recipients before, like "lecture@" can be shared with other people which would be plausible recipients of the mails to such an address.

But are you sure your prof needs and wants to know? He probably only needs the summary, not the details. And students don't even need to share details with you (but usually will even when not asked), but only have to tell the examination office when they ask for extended deadlines and so on. And the examination office has strict privacy requirements, which protect the students.

---

When in doubt, you can always ask the student if you may share the information, or ask them to re-send the e-mail to the professor, or the examination office, or whoever gets the last word on excusing students for sickness. Another reason for this is to stay on the safe side yourself. When you acknowledge something to the student you may be liable when they try to sue the university.

Let's say you answered that their sickness is a valid reason and you believe them and the examination office says they are excluded because they didn't provide proof. Then they may try to sue because you promised something and it wasn't obvious to them that you are not  in the position to make such promises. Or the other way round they take your word and don't get a sickness certificate and later on they have a disadvantage because of it.

Because of such issues it's best to advise the student to contact the relevant people, who can and must make binding promises. When you direct them to the examination office and the examination office says everything's alright, then they can be sure and having them get the confirmation from there is the best for you and the student.

Comment: Why do you think the email address matters so much?

Comment: I'm not aware of any legislation that would prohibit an employee who received information in the course of their work from sharing that with their direct manager (which maps I'd say pretty well to the TA-professor relationship). Certainly nothing in the GDPR would forbid this.

Comment: @Voo, I'm not sure that is true, according to the GDPR guidance I have been given at my institution.  GDPR *may* allow you to pass on information *if* it is demonstrably necessary for people to do their jobs, but you can't pass on personal information where the recipient has no need to have it.  Perhaps my institution is applying GDPR in a very conservative manner.

Comment: @Dikran I guess in a university setting you might end up with more unnecessary personal information than in a business setting where it's usually only information that's required to do the job. That probably informs the various guidelines here. (that said, at least the necessary information should be available to a supervisor - what happens if op becomes sick and someone else has to take over their role?)

Comment: @Voo it is a bit of a nightmare in a university setting.  I chair the "extenuating circumstances panel" in my department, which was set up to minimise the number of people that need to know the details of students extenuating circumstances, so if necessary I can then give guidance to teaching teams without having to pass on the specific details.  But generally GDPR limitations on sharing information has made this sort of thing more difficult.  It clearly wasn't designed with academia in mind.

Comment: @Buffy When someone sends you a mail as a person with a firstname.lastname@ address, than the reasonable expectation is that the mail is only read by you. When someone sends a mail to an address that belongs to a lecture, they cannot even know before who will read it, so it is a smaller issue to share it to another person. The student couldn't know before if the professor or the TA gets the mails that they sent to lecture@, so they probably didn't include details that are for your eyes only.

Comment: Hmmm. I think you made that up. One usually uses the email that they have available. I doubt that anyone would really make such an assumption. Once you hit "send" you lose control of what happens. I think that is the standard assumption. If you want it private or confidential then you need to mark it explicitly as such. And, a TA has no independent authority (US, anyway).

Comment: @Voo, AFAIK, e.g. a priest cannot reveal private information received during counseling (even if it is not a confessional) to their bishop. Or a medical professional health details to a superior who is not involved in the treatment of the patient (or anything not relevant to the treatment). Where I am, a staff council (Betriebsrat) may not reveal to their manager confidential information they receive as staff council. Actually, quite a number of "offices" (exam office, psychological emergeny, disability, ...) at universities deal with various protected/confidential information...

Comment: ... and while they are part of the administrative "command chain", they must preserve confidentiality also "upwards".

Comment: @cbeleites You're not allowed to inform another Betriebsrat about information relevant to your work in that position? So if you get run over by a bus, all the information is simply lost and good luck to the person you were communicating with? That seems.. unwise. In health care relevant information is put into systems to ensure anyone who needs it has access to it and not just a single person. If it's not relevant for the job at hand, sure you shouldn't share it, but why would you in the first place?

Comment: On second thought, I think the crux of the matter is the whole "relevant for the job" part, which I somewhat implicitly assumed. If a bus factor of 1 doesn't matter, you certainly shouldn't share it (not just for privacy reasons, but simply why bother other people with it if it's not relevant?)

Comment: @Voo: yes, the crucial point is **necessity. OP should reveal no more info to their prof than is necessary. Including not revealing confidential information that is relevant for a decision that OP is allowed/supposed to take.

Comment: And a Betriebsrat can discuss with a peer Betriebsrat (similar to 2 MDs who both treat the same patient) - but must preserve confidentiality e.g. with the director. Also Betriebsräte have a normal low-to-medium rank employee position, and their manger there cannot interfere with Betriebsrat-activities. But companies with 5 - 20 employees have only 1 Betriebsrat, so bus f actor 1. So: sufficient importance => documentation, so the replacement Betriebsrat can dig into the case. Everything else => needs to be brought up again. (If OP stops TAing, the student needs to contact the new TA again)

Comment: @Voo thanks for helping me to clarify my mind. I'd express it like this: Where confidential information is involved, one may not only have the *right* to decide but actually the *duty* to decide oneself - in order to preserve confidentiality/privacy.

Comment: @Buffy Maybe many students don't think about the address. Probably many won't care about you sharing health information either. But the one student who thought you keep it confidential and then sues the university is a problem. If you can avoid it, don't share private information. Often I would be happy if people would not share it first time. I cannot even judge their sickness certificate and direct them to the correct examination office. They both can assess if it is valid and have signed the necessary confidentiality forms that make sure they are allowed to handle such information.

Comment: I also see it as respect not to share private information without prior consent, even when I am allowed. And the easiest way to share it with explicit consent is to ask the student to send the information to the right person and give them the correct address so they can just re-sent the mail. Then it's no longer your problem to decide if you have the implicit permission or not.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add a few points mainly to @DikranMarsupial's and @all's answers.

- First of all, I'd like to thank you for being careful about student privacy.
- You can always **put the case in anonymized/pseudonymized fashion to your prof**. E.g. saying, "A student asks for extension because of private reasons. From what they told me, I think it's genuine. Is that something I can decide? On what reasons should I grant the extension, on what reasons not?"

  Even better would be to ask/organize a session of all involved with the course where the prof outlines the policy. You may start an (anonymized) case collection for future use.
- Personally*, I'd "negotiate" with the student, telling them that you cannot decide this on your own and will have to consult the professor. Offer that you put the case in anonymized fashion but ask them how *they* want you to proceed in case the prof asks for details. I.e., whether they want you reveal details in that case or rather keep their privacy at the cost of not getting the extension.

  *I'm not a junior TA any more. With a standing of almost 20 a of professional experience I'd take a stand shielding a student's privacy against any head of course, professor or institute director where I judge that is what needs to be done.
- You mention **mental health problems revealed**: a privacy-friendly way of asking your prof would e.g. be "In case a student reveals mental health problems, where do I refer them? Do I need to inform someone or do I just tell the student where they can go for help?"

  Personally (and according to how things work where I am), I'd possibly tell the student anyways that they may want to consider getting a medical certificate. These medical certificates over here say basically "X is unable to work". They don't reveal reason/diagnosis but they legally mean that the student must get appropriate accommodation.
  (BTW, university policy may anyways require the student to bring one)
- **student revealing too much private information**: you may find that students tell you more than is actually required, and more than you'd have liked to know (see next point).

  It may be important feedback to the student that you think they revealed more private information than necessary.
- It may be stressful *to you* to know private details the student volunteered (e.g. in case of health or harrassment). This is part of the TAing/teaching profession, although likely noone ever taught you about it. And it is part of the teaching profession* that you must keep this information appropriately private.

  I'm writing this because I've witnessed an occasion where private student information was inappropriately revealed by a head of course. And I think this happened (also) because the head of course needed to relieve *their* stress by telling someone (which turned out to be a whole group of TAs).  This was all very sympathetic, but still definitively inappropriate and unprofessional. All we needed to know was that in case of *X* happening, we should do *Y*.

  Some professions (medical, psychological, pastors, ...) regularly face similar stress. They have supervision processes established to deal with this in a way that doesn't violate privacy.

  In case you need that, it's fine to talk to someone in a way that keeps the student anonymous (maybe not even mentioning it's one of your students). One key thing to keep in mind here is: your close colleagues or friends from the department/university are not a good choice: the risk that the student's identity is accidentally revealed by circumstances entirely outside your control is substantial.

  *It's actually not that rare: If you move to industry and become team lead or manager, similar things are likely to happen. Even if you volunteer as trainer in the local sports team, head a scout group, ...

Comment: +1 excellent points - especially about the burden of knowing the details of students personal difficulties.  One of the advantages of having an extenuating circumstances panel is that TAs and faculty members can ask me (as chair) to reach out to the student to advise them of where they can get help and support (as a computer scientist I can help them with debugging their C++, but I am not qualified to help them directly with anything more complicated than that, but I can signpost)

Comment: My own experience is that when a TA is encouraged by a student not to talk to a prof is that often they've already talked to the prof, or are shopping TAs for an amenable response

Comment: @ScottSeidman: in the first case, the prof's reply to the anonymized description would be along the lines of "if that's about student S, it's OK, they talked to me [or not]". Case solved. Shopping TAs: when/where I was TAing, the typical setup was that each TA had "their" students assigned to them, so impossible to shop other than trying both TA and prof separately.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are aware of the policy for granting extensions at your university.  It is possible that the prof is not involved in the process.  At my university, each department has an "extenuating circumstances panel", which has the discretion to grant extensions etc. rather than being dealt with informally by the teaching team.  The main reason for this is to limit the number of faculty that need to know personal information that the student may not want widely known, but also to ensure consistency and fairness across courses/modules.

The "golden rule" is quite useful in such situations, consider whether you would want the prof to know the information if you were the student and act accordingly.  You can always ask the student if they mind you passing on the information.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt just cc your professor on your response email. Calling in sick or other small things not really worth it.
If you're actually worrying about the student, it's usually best to call the professor. Most schools have an anonymous system to refer students to people that can actually do something about mental health.

Comment: Calling in sick *repeatedly* is certainly a matter for the prof.  For all the TA knows, the student may be rotating through a stack of TAs, and the only hope of knowing the situation is if the prof monitors all such requests.

Answer (score 1):

US Specific (non GDRP):
If it's concerning a student in a course, the student should have very little expectation of privacy over any communication you have about it with the course director.

Much of what the prof would like communication about is going to be up to the prof.  For individual types of scenarios, like a student asking for an extension, for some courses TAs may be empowered to make those decisions, and for others, they may not be.  Even if you are empowered to make such decisions on your own, many profs would still want to know who is handing in work late, and when it comes in.

Bottom line, the prof has responsibility for teaching the students and issuing a fair grade based upon performance, and is entitled to all the information surrounding that endeavor.  Sometimes a prof may allow TAs to make some decisions, but that doesn't relieve profs of their responsibility, and they might choose to keep track of things.

Comment: As I understand it, GDPR, at least as applies in the UK means that the student does have a right to expect privacy over communications relating to personal information.  We *don't* have a right to share it without demonstrably good cause.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial  I edited to specify this as non-GDRP advice, but it's a tough sell for me that GDRP would dramatically change things, as I don't understand how the relationship between a TA and a course director can be anything OTHER than that of joint data controllers.  If a TA changes a grade on a homework, does the TA need to solicit the consent of the student to pass the grade along to the course director??  The data is staying completely within the confines of legitimate agents of the organization it was sent to, limited to those who need to know what the data is to do

Comment: @ScottSeideman the TA *isn't* a data controller, I suspect they should not have been the person that received the information at all.  Grades are not in the same category as personal information.  I have had discussions with the GDPR specialists at my university (as I chair an Extenuating Circumstances Panel, and thus have to see a lot of student's personal information), and it is not at all clear what constitutes "legitimate agents" for these sorts of things (obviously *I* am one of them, but I am not generally allowed to share details with my colleagues that teach the student).

Comment: @DikranMarsupial We have offices here that assess students' accommodations.  When an accommodation is granted under that office, profs (not TAs) get a notification of what accommodation is to be offered, but not any of the data underlying that decision, which is confidential.  My syllabi have specific language that requests for accommodation under any other path may not be held confidential (due to a case where I had sleepness nights over a student in distress, and eventually asked them if I could contact others as sensitively as I could).

Comment: "I had sleepness nights over a student in distress," I know what that is like - it was one of the things that prompted me to have discussions with our GDPR specialists (who were unable to tell me explicitly whether my "emergency plans" were actually GDPR compliant).  I like the idea of GDPR, but the implementation seems problematic, at least for academia.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial -- it also seems like compliance officers and legal staff often go over the top to protect the institutions, minimizing risks, without actually caring about whether the recommended treatments are actually required by statute or worrying about what obstacles they're creating or how much work an unnecessary treatment can generate.

Comment: I think it is at least partly that it isn't clear how GDPR should apply in academia, it may not have been a use case they really had in mind.  I got (just) enough reassurance that I would probably be O.K.